# After set up testng is not running

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

what is wrong in the code of set up environment to not run the code

kindly guide for it

```
package tc1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC001 {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass

    public void launchBrowser(){    

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }

    @Test

    public void login(){

        driver.get("http://www.meritnation.com/testprep");

        driver.findElement(By.className("login-link")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(50000);

    }

    @AfterClass

    public void browserClose(){

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

there is showing zero run and zero fail by running testng enter code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZMTc.png)

> [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1256807320\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> =============================================== Default test
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> =============================================== Default suite
>
> Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 3
>   ms
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1eb44e46: 1 ms
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@ea30797: 56 ms
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1963006a: 26
>   ms
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@1ee0005: 9 ms
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6bf2d08e: 66 ms

Comment: How are you triggering the test?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is I think you need to change `@Before` to `@BeforeClass`

Also I wasn't sure what imports you use (and I just blindly did Ctrl+Shift+o in eclipse), or what website you were going to but I figured I would give a shot at giving you a working class, so I hope this helps:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC001 {

       //  WebDriver driver;
         public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

           @BeforeClass
           public void launchBrowser() {



              driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
           //   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

           //    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           }

           @Test
           public void login() {

               driver.findElement(By.className("login-link")).click();

               //Thread.sleep(50000);
           }
           @AfterClass
           public void browserClose() {

               driver.quit();
           }


}
```

Update: 
When I ran your code it failed with 1 failure.  Since your seeing, 0 run, I would ask

1. Could you try "Project clean" in eclipse (or whatever your IDE
   is).
2. Try closing restarting your IDE

   - make sure You have testNG installed in your IDE, If you can actually
     get it to run, then we move on to the next problem.

   You are doing some unusual things with the driver. Your declaring 2 different things as your "driver".
   -Try doing the `public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` like I have in my answer,

   - Remove the `FirefoxDriver` line from your `@beforeclass` method,
   - Also use driver.navigate in the `@beforeclass.`

Comment: One more thing, I removed the timeout because I didn't feel like waiting that long for it to fail.  Feel free to uncomment it.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Comment: Unlike JUnit, TestNG is designed to work with non `static` attributes in `@Before/AfterClass` methods.

Answer (score 0):

**driver** has been declared twice. The @BeforeClass method is creating a local instance of FirefoxDriver which is not accessible within @Test method. Remove 'FirefoxDriver' within @BeforeClass where you creating an instance of FirefoxDriver(). Or in other words replace `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`  with  `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` in @BeforeClass method.

So, it will look somewhat like this:

```
public class TC001 {

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass

public void launchBrowser(){    

  driver = new FirefoxDriver ();

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}
```

//remaining code as it is